Quill editor multi indent list use classes instead of html tags
I am using Quill as a rich text editor in my Angular project. While it's functioning well overall, I encountered an issue when creating nested lists. When I pass the HTML content to downstream systems, both the indentation and numbering break.
After some research, I discovered that Quill uses classes like ql-indent-1, ql-indent-2, ql-indent-3, etc., for nested lists. Unfortunately, the downstream systems cannot interpret these "ql-indent-x" classes.
I would like Quill to generate standard HTML using regular UL, OL, and LI tags for nested lists, without the custom ql-indent classes. This way, the downstream systems can properly consume the HTML content.
How can I configure Quill to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!
I tried to replace the "ql-indent-x" classes wuth inline styles but that is not working as expected and number/ordering of lists still messed in downstrem system.

You should override Quill's native formats. This guide will show you how that works and you can just customize how ol/ul/li works. https://quilljs.com/docs/guides/cloning-medium-with-parchment
